# Possible use of @media print .button:hover

Tags: css

I found the following CSS:

```
@media print {
  .button:hover {
    background: #ACDD4A;
  }
}
```

What would be its possible use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like whoever wrote that simply doesn't understand the concept of [printing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printing) — I don't know of any paged media that supports hover interaction :)

Even if the intent was to override a different `.button:hover` rule in the main (screen) stylesheet, it's still useless anyway, as you may have surmised.

Answer (score 0):

print is for .... printing on paper, so can you hover over a picture in you favorite magazine and see something changing?

Print media does not support `:hover`